# How to iterate through a column in a table and perform certain action based on certain conditions using watir

Tags: html

New to watir and here is the challenge I have for the below requirement

1. I have a table with multiple columns.
2. The first column has list of items(in each row) with a '+' sign before it. Rest of the columns are basically numbers corresponding
   to the first column like "Revenue", "Loss" etc
3. Clicking on each plus sign in the first column in each row (which basically expands the hierarchy) will indent its child item by
   certain points (the attribute used is "style=padding-left:52px;;"
   for indentation).
4. This clicking process on the '+' has to stop till I dont find a 'plus'(expand) sign to click.
5. Then I have to go back in reverse order and check if the total of the child item equals the parent starting from column 2 and the rest
   of the columns in the table which are basically reported numbers
   6.If there are multiple child items for a single parent they all will be at the same indentation level.

Here is what I want to do:

1. Iterate through each row in the first column.
2. Click on the '+' or expand sign in each row of the first column till I dont find the '+' sign (signifying I have reached last node)
3. Now,compare the left padding attribute and its pixel count mentioned in point 3 of requirement section.
4. If they are different, compare the value from column2 and if they are same, put it as pass, else fail.
5. If pixel count is same for multiple rows in the first column add up all the values from column 2 and compare it against its parent (who will have a lesser count of left padding pixel when compared to its child).

Comment: Could you please reformat your question ? It's not easy to read like this.

Comment: Ok Awad, let me try to put it this way. Taking one step at a time.